# PowerShell Install of Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers

Tags: powershell, webdeploy

I need to install Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers. Normally you would use the Web Platform Installer, but I need to deploy this using PowerShell. I have found the download for Web Deploy 3.6 and can use PowerShell to install the .MSI of that, but that is different that Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers.

Does anyone know where I can download Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers or know how to use PowerShell to install via the Web Platform Installer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: How is it off topic. It directly correlates to using PowerShell to install Web Deploy for Hosting Servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have located the answer. The Web Platform Installer has an API so you can call the .exe with PowerShell akin to this:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPICMD.exe" /List /ListOption:Available
```

There are install options as noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release

Comment: This is deprecated and not usable anymore
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/429383/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-and-sunsetti