# How to install web deploy using PowerShell using Complete Installation Selection

Tags: powershell, installation, azure-powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying installing Web Deploy 3.6 on my Azure VM using PowerShell but it's only installing the minimum features and I want to install All the Features available in the installer (Complete).

How can I do this?

I'm using a command something like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" -ArgumentList "/quiet /passive"
```

Comment: Then have a look at the .msi's full command line options.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055861/45375), `ADDLOCAL=ALL` selects all features, though the design of a given `.msi` file may still exclude features that way. If that is a case, a _transform file_ is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Follow the below ways to install All features of `.msi` file

#### Using `ALLLOCAL = ALL`

Using **ALLLOCAL = ALL** command ***install*** all features in the MSI on the local disk. Which is already Commented by @[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" -ArgumentList "ADDLOCAL=ALL /quiet /qn"
```

#### Using `InstallMode`

**InstallMode=Complete** command which allows you to install all Features of the **.msi** file.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" -ArgumentList "/quiet \qn InstallMode=Complete"
```

> **Note:** Before using this **InstallMode=Complete** Command make sure to check the Vendor. Because It depends on how the MSI file was created by the vendor.

#### Few References

1. [PowerShell Install of Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289193/15997690)
2. [Powershell installing msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987977/powershell-installing-msi)
3. [InstallMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.2) & [ADDLOCAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/addlocal)

Comment: Nice, but re `InstallMode` you accidentally linked to the unrelated `Install-Module` PowerShell cmdlet. Also, the MSI [property reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference) has no such (public) property (and if it did, it would be have to uppercased on the command line). Can you clarify further under what conditions `InstallMode=Complete` works, and perhaps give few examples?

Comment: Refer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1276996/How-to-install-a-msi-file-with-custom-option-with)

Comment: Thanks, but please update your answer directly, especially to fix the incorrect "InstallMode" link. The link in your latest comment doesn't tell you any more than what is already in the answer, unfortunately.